# Gitlab SSH connection is timed out, but using HTTP(S) works fine

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ipv6, ipv4

*Tip: the SSH key is perfectly configured on my machine and on Gitlab, so apparently it is not an authentication problem, but a connection problem.*

When I am connected to my home network and I try to connect to Gitlab via SSH `(ssh -v git@gitlab.com)` the connection is timed out and fails.
Then the process tries to connect again, now using IPv4, and then the connection is made successfully (after several minutes of waiting) and this is the output:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

However, if I connect to any other network, the connection is made successfully, resulting in this output:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u7, OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Apparently it is a problem on my home network or on Gitlab, but I have tried everything and tried a lot for possible solutions, without success.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You could configure your system to prefer ipv4 (instead of ipv6) but that won't help with whatever other network filtering is apparently happening here. For ipv4/ipv6 precedence on Linux, see https://serverfault.com/questions/93717/setting-ipv4-as-preferred-protocol-over-ipv6

Comment: If your network supports IPv6, then you need to figure out why it's not working or it's being filtered.  if your network doesn't support IPv6, you need to figure out why you're getting a valid global IPv6 address.  Try Super User or Unix & Linux if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was my network. I tried pinging gitlab using http://ipv6now.com.au/pingme.php and it worked. When I issued the ping command from my local workstation it did not work. I changed my work station to prefer ipv4 using instructions that I found here, http://sf-alpha.bjgang.org/wordpress/2012/08/linux-prefer-ipv4-over-ipv6-in-dual-stack-environment-and-prevent-problems-when-only-ipv4-exists/. In essence, I uncommented and changed the line in /etc/gai.conf from
`precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10`
to
`precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100`